# iterate ansible task with variable

Tags: loops, ansible, ansible-2.x

i wish to take the output of a shell command and use that as input to run another command multiple times with each item as and arg:

```
---
- hosts: myhost
  tasks:

    - name: determine local storage mount points
      shell: /usr/sbin/showmount -d | grep -v Directories
      register: mounts

    - debug: var=mounts.stdout_lines

    - name: run gather script
      shell: echo gather.py {{item}}
      register: gather
      with_items: "{{mounts.stdout_lines}}"
```

how do i do this?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. What's wrong?

Comment: Yep. I just took your code and use it for template for something else. In my case shutting down docker containers. That worked. Did you get any failed messages?

Comment: @yee379 the only difference i got there is I used `command` instead of `shell`
See my example: https://github.com/SamuelToh/2147483647_story_ptr_project/blob/master/ansible/02-iteration-in-ansible/task.yml

Comment: @yee379 - your shell command doesn't look quite right `echo gather.py {{item}}` Is `echo` supposed to be `python`?

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking your code is correct and it should work. However the `shell` command for `echo gather.py {{item}}` could be your problem.

Looking at the file extension for gather, I suspect you are trying to execute a python script? So doing an `echo` would not make any sense here.

Instead, you might want to try `python gather.py {{item}}`.